# Angular insert a char-limit: Property 'invalid' does not exist on type 'HTMLTextAreaElement'. Did you mean 'oninvalid'?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-ngmodel, angular-translate

I want to add a character limit and I did this:

but it shows an error by "invalid" last line

```
<mat-form-field class="fbinput" appearance="outline" style="white-space: pre-wrap;" [formGroup]="myForm" > 
  <textarea
    [(ngModel)]="enteredContent"
    id="content"
    matInput rows="6"
    name="content"
    required
    [maxlength]="maxChars"
    formControlName="wordLimitation"
    placeholder="{{'Feedback.notizEingeben' | translate}}"
    #content
    ngModel="content"
    
    
      >
  </textarea>
  <mat-error *ngIf="content.invalid">{{'Warnung.feedbackEingeben' | translate}}</mat-error>
```

before the code was like this and had no errors

What can i do??

```
<mat-form-field class="fbinput" appearance="outline" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
  <textarea
    [(ngModel)]="enteredContent"
    id="content"
    matInput rows="6"
    name="content"
    required
    placeholder="{{'Feedback.notizEingeben' | translate}}"
    #content="ngModel">
  </textarea>
  <mat-error *ngIf="content.invalid">{{'Warnung.feedbackEingeben' | translate}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
  
</mat-form-field>
```

What can i do??
can someone help

Comment: Why did you replace `#content="ngModel"` by `#content ngModel="content"` ? The first way tells Angular: "declare a variable named 'content' whose value is the directive NgModel". That's why you can use `content.invalid` afterward.

Comment: if i #content="ngModel"

insert then the error comes

"No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'  "
what do i have to do?

Comment: You have to import FormsModule in the module declaring this component.